# Prevent form redirection onsubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am working on an HTML form. When I hit the submit button, it downloads a file from a server. However, when an error occurs at the server, it redirects to another page. I want to prevent the redirect from happening. I tried using AJAX for the same but then I do not get a download link.

Is there a way to make it work by successfully downloading a file from the server or displaying an error message at the same page if there is an error at the server-side.

I am using Java at server-side.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language you r using at server side.. ?

Answer (score 1):

you didnt provide some code to make it , but I am always doing it in Ajax and prevent form to do any action if there is some error

so i have this code maybe it helps

```
  $( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    var downloadData = {
      id : fileid //fileid
    }

    $.ajax({
      url : '../download.php',
      type : 'POST',
      data : downloadData,
      success : function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          // download the file or window.location to file path
      },
      error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // show error message
      }
    });
  });
```